# jQuery chosen change display 2 level after select

Tags: javascript, html

How would I be able to display select menu  when someone select the value option in style id? Code is like this.
HTML :

```
  <div class="row">
        <select name="style" id="style">
                <option value="banner"></option>
                <option value="text"></option>
                <option value="vedio"></option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <select name="language" id="language" style="display:none;">
                <option value="EN"></option>
                <option value="ES"></option>
                <option value="FR"></option>
            </select>
            </div>
           <div class="row">
            <select name="english" id="english" style="display:none;">
                <option value="text"></option>
                <option value="img"></option>
                <option value="vedio"></option>
            </select>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
            <select name="spanish" id="spanish" style="display:none;">
                <option value="text"></option>
                <option value="img"></option>
                <option value="vedio"></option>
            </select>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
            <select name="french" id="french" style="display:none;" >
                <option value="text"></option>
                <option value="img"></option>
                <option value="vedio"></option>
            </select>
            </div>
```

SCRIPT :

```
  $('#style').change(function(){
       selection = $(this).val();
       switch(selection)
       {
           case 'text':
               $('#language').show();
               break;
           default:
               $('#language').hide();
               break;
       }
    });
    $('#language').change(function(){
       selection = $(this).val();
       switch(selection)
       {
           case 'EN':
               $('#english').show();
               break;
           default:
               $('#english').hide();
               break;
       }
    });
```

i want select text value i get language choice when i select language i get anther select menu

Comment: i can't understand , could u explane more

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`selection = $(this).val();`

to

```
selection = $('#style option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) `$('#language')` and your selects have no ids. You should give ids to each of your selects or use the [attribute-equals](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector `$('[name="language"]')` instead.